# Cómo pasar un atributo desde el controlador a diferentes JSP en Java

Tags: java, mvc, spring, jsp, backend

Desde un controlador, necesito setear un atributo en el `JSP` utilizando `Java`, en mi controlador tengo algo así.

```
if( ! obtenerNumero.getId().equals("") ) {
    request.setAttribute( "numero", 1 );
} 
else {
    request.setAttribute( "numero", 2 );
}
```

Es algo tan simple como verificar si existe o no el número, si existe se le asigna el valor "`1`", de lo contrario el "`2`". Con eso, debo validar en el `JSP` para que muestre un alerta.

```
<c:if test="${numero == '1'}">
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
<strong>Ud. </strong> está mostrando un numero
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></c:if>
</button>
```

La idea es mostrar ese alerta cuando el valor es "`1`", pero creo que no me lo está tomando porque no muestra nada, me he fijado con `debug` que asigne el valor 1 en el controlador y si lo hace, solo que falta enviar ese dato al `JSP`. Espero puedan ayudarme gracias!!!

Comment: Hola Emerson, los Snipets solo funcionan con **html css y javascript**.

Comment: Te recomiendo indagar más al respecto del uso del tag `<c:if>`, por el código que muestras probablemente te haga falta alguna configuración, te recomiendo leer al respecto, [aquí hay más información](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/11/jstl-cif-core-tag/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Era algo tan sencillo como agregarle la sesión, quedaría algo así.

```java
request.getSession().setAttribute( "numero", 2 );
```

Con esa acción, puedo pasar el valor 2 con el nombre del atributo "numero" a cualquier JSP.